# JavaScript ColdFusion CFGrid row manipulation

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have setup a `CFGrid` which displays a list of records and it needs to be able to have the selected record deleted. However, I'm getting the following error: **"Error: The value of the property 'deleteAssignment' is null or undefined, not a Function object".** From what I've seen, others have setup functions very similarly which did not throw that error. My code is below

**CFGrid Code:**

```
<cfform height="200" id="empGridForm" name="empGridForm">
    <cfgrid name="employeePerspective" format="html" striperows="yes" 
    delete="yes" query="qEmployeeAssignments" height="200" selectmode="row">
    <cfgridcolumn name="employeeName" header="Last Name" width="200"/>
    <cfgridcolumn name="reportName"  header="Report Name" width="200" />
    <cfgridcolumn name="reportDescrip" header="Report Description"  
    width="300"/>
    </cfgrid>
<cfinput type="button" name="newEmp" label="Add Employee" value="Add 
Employee" id="addEmployeebtn">
<cfinput type="button" name="DeleteEmp" label="Delete Employee"    
value="Delete  
Employee" id="deleteEmployeebtn" onClick="deleteAssignment();">
</cfform>
```

**Javascript to delete selected datagrid row:**

```
    <cfajaxproxy cfc="deleteFunc" jsclassname="Users">
    <script language="javascript">

    function deleteAssignment() {                                               <!---javascript delete function to remove selected employee from assigment--->
    var selectedRecord = employeePerspective.getSelections();                   <!--- This variable 'selectedRecord' is set to the datagrid selected value --->
    var employeeName = selectedRecord[0].data.employeeName;                     <!---This deleteRecord variable is set to  the datagrid selected value stored in variable selectedRecord--->
    if(confirm('Delete Employee: ' + selectedRecord[0].data.employeeName))      <!--- This generates a confirmation window. When confirmed variable deleteRecord passed to CFC delete function--->
    {
        objeUser.delUser(employeeName);                                         <!---This line passes deleteRecord variable into CFC method and executes delete method--->
    };
    }

    var objUser = new Users();                                                  <!--- This line sets a JS variable equal to a Coldfusion function located in coldfusionFunction.cfc file--->
    objUser.setErrorHandler(showError);                                         <!--- This line sets an error handling method --->
    objectUser.setCallbackHandler(handleResult);                                <!--- This line sets callback method which will refresh the grid --->

    function handleResult(res) {                                                <!---This line sets the event handler which will refresh the grid upon execution of delete function --->
        Coldfusion.Grid.refresh('employeePerspective',false);
    }

    function showError()                                                        <!--- This is the error handling function. Called when the delete function is unsuccessful --->
    {
        alert("Your attempt to delete the selected record was unsuccessful. Try again or contact administrator");
</script>
```

The JavaScript function is to pass the datagrid value into the CFC using the `cfajaxproxy` where the function would run the `cfquery` to complete the deletion then JavaScript refreshes the grid without a page refresh.